# Calcular la posición en una circunferencia de varios usuarios en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, math

he tenido problemas intentando diseñar una fórmula que me permita asignar una posición equidistante a varios usuarios en función de la cantidad de usuarios disponibles. Algo así:

```
victima1 = 180
victima2 = victima1 + 180
asalvo1  =  victima1 + ((180/3) * 1)
asalvo2 =  victima1 + ((180/3) * 2)
asalvo3 =  victima2 + ((180/2) * 1)
```

Había pensado en usar algo como

```
θ = n / 360
```

Donde θ es la circunferencia disponible y n es el número de usuarios. A partir de este resultado podría calcular la posición, pero no sé cómo.
Únicamente deseo obtener la posición en grados de cada usuario para colocarlos en un círculo. Así si hay 5 jugadores se asignará una posición donde la distancia entre ellos es igual. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediante el uso de una **lista** puedes almacenar los resultados de los ángulos que le corresponderían a **n** personas, tal cual como propones se puede utilizar la fórmula para saber cuál es la distancia entre cada persona, así el código podría ser como el siguiente

```
cantidad_personas = 5
angulo = 360 / cantidad_personas
lista_angulos = []

for i in range(cantidad_personas):
    lista_angulos.append(angulo * i)

print(lista_angulos)
```

Da como resultado:

```
[0.0, 72.0, 144.0, 216.0, 288.0]
```